# How can I get man to see $HOME/share/man pages?

Tags: centos, manpage

According to the man page, "manpath" should just echo out the contents of ${MANPATH} when that is set in the environment.  (It is exported.)

```
$ echo $MANPATH
/usr/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/X11R6/man:/home/me/shar/man
$ manpath
/usr/share/man/overrides:/usr/share/man:/usr/share/man/en:/usr/local/share/man
```

I got to doing this because I wanted the man page in /home/me/shar/man/man1/whatever.1
This works:

```
man -M $HOME/share/man/man1 whatever
```

but these do not:

```
man -M $MANPATH whatever
man -M $MANPATH/man1 whatever

$ uname -a ; man --version ; cat /etc/system-release
Linux mysystem 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
man, version 1.6f
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
```

I've used it before successfully on other Linux/UNIX distros, but it's failing on this one.

Comment: I'd double check the `MANPATH`. It seems that the relevant part has a typo: `/home/me/shar/man`. It can explain what you see.

Comment: It's a locally built man page for the sharutils?  Maybe not.  TY.